# Forgot Password issue in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, hash, laravel-4

Here i get the username in the forgot password option and i am trying to change the password (Custom way temporarily - Don't mind about it)

```
$UserData = Input::except(array('_token'));
        $UserDetails = User::where('username', $UserData)->get()->toArray();             
        $user = User::find($UserDetails[0]['Id']);
        $str = str_random(5);
        $user->password = $str;            
        $user->save();
```

And inside the Model i use the

```
public function setpasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    }
```

As i am not using `Hash::make(Input::get('password'))`. I guess that the laravel is hashing some empty value and storing.

How can i do just Hash the password which i have as `$str`  with something like `$this->attributes['password'] = $str;` like this ?

**(I mean only the $str should be hashed)**

Comment: You could use `$user->password = Hash::make($str);`

Comment: As i use `setpasswordAttribute` it will hash again right

Comment: You need to check whether Input has password attribute.  
`public function setpasswordAttribute($value)
    {
if(Input::has('password'))
{
$this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
}
}`

Comment: No, it is not working, it is making some hashed password :(

Comment: So i am using directly like `DB::table('admin_profile')->where('Id', $UserDetails[0]['Id'])->update(array('password' => Hash::make($string)));` Is it possible by using only Model Name (Not using table name) in the update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is wrong. It should be this:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
 {
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
 }
```

Comment: I updated that, Even after changing i didn't do `$comment->password = Hash::make($string);`  as it is hashing inside model. but still it hashes some other value. What might be the mistake

Comment: I dont understand. Do you want the model to hash the supplied data or not?

Comment: Sorry I got it The thing happening is , i already do  `$user->password = Hash::make($string);`  at the same time it is hashed another time in model. So double hashed (value will surely be wrong). So i removed the old hash in controller and made the change as you suggested in model and got it worked. Thanks